# Combine list with vector in R

Tags: r

I have some data like the following:

```
num = list()
num[[1]] = c(1,2,3)
num[[2]] = c(4,5,6,7)
name = c("Alex", "Patrick")
```

How do I combine it into a data frame that looks like this?

```
Alex        1
Alex        2
Alex        3
Patrick     4
Patrick     5
Patrick     6
Patrick     7
```

I'm sorry for posting what's likely an obvious question. I've searched extensively and not found the answer, probably because I don't know how to describe this query well.

Comment: `stack(setNames(num, name))`

Comment: @user20650 add as an answer, new function of the day - stack!

Comment: @zx8754; ha, yup i rarely remember it. .. but I think i'll leave it to loiter in the comments, as its really just doing what Richard S's answer does, but with clothes on.

Comment: @user20650 Fantastic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this a try.  The new `lengths()` function comes in handy here.

```
data.frame(name = rep(name, lengths(num)), num = unlist(num))
#      name num
# 1    Alex   1
# 2    Alex   2
# 3    Alex   3
# 4 Patrick   4
# 5 Patrick   5
# 6 Patrick   6
# 7 Patrick   7
```

To understand this a little better, let's break it into parts from the inside out.  `lengths()` tells us the lengths of each element in a list, so we have

```
lengths(num)
# [1] 3 4
```

Now we use that as the `times` argument in `rep()` to replicate the elements of `name`.

```
rep(name, lengths(num))
# [1] "Alex"    "Alex"    "Alex"    "Patrick" "Patrick" "Patrick" "Patrick"
```

So that's the first column.  For the second column, we just turn `num` into an atomic vector with `unlist()`.

```
unlist(num)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Put these together as shown above and we have your new data frame.

Comment: This is brilliant. A little hard to follow the nested functions but I think I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexLach - I have added some explanation.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
data.table::rbindlist(Map(function(x,y) data.frame(name = x, num = y), name, num))
      name num
1:    Alex   1
2:    Alex   2
3:    Alex   3
4: Patrick   4
5: Patrick   5
6: Patrick   6
7: Patrick   7
```

Answer (score 2):

Or we can use `stack` after setting the `names` of 'num' with 'name'

```
stack(setNames(num, name))[2:1]
#      ind values
#1    Alex      1
#2    Alex      2
#3    Alex      3
#4 Patrick      4
#5 Patrick      5
#6 Patrick      6
#7 Patrick      7
```

Just noticed that this was posted in the comments by @user20650.  In that case, we can also do

```
library(reshape2)
melt(setNames(num, name))[2:1]
#       L1 value
#1    Alex     1
#2    Alex     2
#3    Alex     3
#4 Patrick     4
#5 Patrick     5
#6 Patrick     6
#7 Patrick     7
```